# Drawing a simple Markov chain in a "triangle inequality" configuration

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use Tikz to graph a simple Markov chain with three nodes. The first node is labelled s = 1, the second node is labelled s = 2, and the third node is labelled s = 3. All are connected via straight, undirected edges. But the problem is that I want the chain in a "triangle inequality" kind of shape, where node s = 2 is between s = 1 and s = 3, but off to the side a bit, so that it has a kind of triangle shape. This image from the [Wikipedia article for triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) illustrates what I mean:

[image]

The nodes would be the vertices.

I can't find any tutorials that show how to do such a thing. How is this done?

---

### EDIT

The closest demonstrations I can find are things like this:

[image]

(From https://ai.plainenglish.io/fraudulent-transaction-detection-using-markov-model-from-scratch-b26e6bf9bc0d)

But I want a configuration like this:

[image]

(From https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Inference-and-minimization-of-hidden-Markov-chains-Gillman-Sipser/88e08bd20b2ffc201eb92f3d073e06df92bb9fad)

---

### EDIT2

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to compile:

```
% Author: Till Tantau
% Source: The PGF/TikZ manual

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

  \node[initial,state] (A)                    {$q_a$};
  \node[state]         (B) [above right of=A] {$q_b$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right of=A]       {$q_c$};

  \path (A) edge              node  (B)
            edge              node  (C)
        (B) edge              node  (C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT3

Got it:

```
% Author: Till Tantau
% Source: The PGF/TikZ manual

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

  \node[initial,state] (A)                    {$s = 1$};
  \node[state]         (B) [above right of=A] {$s = 2$};
  \node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$s = 3$};

  \path (A) edge              node {a1} (B)
            edge              node {a2} (C)
        (B) edge              node {a3} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But for some reason it won't let me use a_1, a_2, a_3, so I have to use a1, a2, a3.

Comment: You can place one node at 0, 0; one at 4, 0 and one at 2, 1? Can you add a sketch of what you're trying to achieve and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I have added some edits to my post.

Comment: When you draw a line, you can add nodes along it, say `\draw (0) -- node[above]{1/2} (1);`. The manual covers this in its tutorials and explains the finer details later on. Take a look around here or at texample.net and you will surely find something. [Automata](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/) are their own category.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel See my second edit. It seems like I'd want the state machine rather than the automata.

Comment: @ThePointer: Adding edit upon edit to the original question doesn't help. If an edit supersedes a previous one, just keep the latest one. Think about future users who land here - would they benefit from headings like **Edit 1**, **Edit 2**, ...? No. Write your question in a way that will make any visitor understand the purpose without having to negotiate a timeline stemming from a bunch of comments (that may not be there in the future).

Comment: @Werner Understood. I thought showing the history and progression of edits would actually help other users, but I see your point.

Comment: @ThePointer: An answer to your question (not posted as part of the question) should capture the solution. That way someone landing here can read a clear question, and see a definitive answer; not a mix of edits and associated comments. It does make sense to you, but not the general (future) public.

Comment: If you want to use a subscript you will need to use math mode, i.e. `{$a_1$}` and so on.